# Do I need an separate EFI partition for each OS sharing a common disk?

Tags: freebsd, dual-boot, uefi, refind

I was installing  FreeBSD on my MacBook Air. When partitioning the disk, the installer told me

> `This partition scheme requires a boot partition for the disk to be bootable. Would you like to make one now? <Yes/No>`

The problem is, I already have an EFI partition on my internal SSD, which presumably serves macOS. Do I need to create a different one for FreeBSD?

I've done some *painful* experiments on this issue:

- When I chose `No`, FreeBSD becomes unbootable, i.e. "FreeBSD" is simply not shown in rEFInd's menu.
- When I chose `Yes`, "the FreeBSD installer appears to have created a very bad [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) on your disk, and this is confusing OS X", and thus [my disk got corrupted](https://superuser.com/questions/1213606/storage-space-disappeared-on-internal-ssd-of-macbook-air/1214031#1214031). Fortunately, after I follow [@Rod Smith's instruction](https://superuser.com/a/1214031/554799) (created a new protective MBR to replace the bad hybrid MBR), this problem is solved now, but now my disk have 2 EFI partitions.

  Now my internal SSD looks like this:

  ```
  sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:~ sunqingyao$ diskutil list
  /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            60.6 GB    disk0s2
     3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
     4:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s4
     5:                FreeBSD UFS                         53.5 GB    disk0s5
     6:               FreeBSD Swap                         6.2 GB     disk0s6
     7: 83BD6B9D-7F41-11DC-BE0B-001560B84F0F               101.4 KB   disk0s7
  ```

  Also,

  ```
  sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:~ sunqingyao$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
  Password:
        start       size  index  contents
            0          1         PMBR
            1          1         Pri GPT header
            2         32         Pri GPT table
           34          6
           40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  118284248      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    118693888    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    119963424     409600      4  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    120373024  104447992      5  GPT part - 516E7CB6-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
    224821016   12156928      6  GPT part - 516E7CB5-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
    236977944        198      7  GPT part - 83BD6B9D-7F41-11DC-BE0B-001560B84F0F
    236978142          1
    236978143         32         Sec GPT table
    236978175          1         Sec GPT header
  ```

Comment: Generally speaking, no, you do not need separate EFI partitions for each OS. For example, I have NixOS (Linux) installed along side MacOS, using systemd-boot as the boot manager, both on the same EFI filesystem. But your question is more specific than that; it's about properly installing FreeBSD on an UEFI system.